# How can I use jq to parse this string?

Tags: arrays, json, jq, aws-cli

The CommandID string is not behaving as I would expect when I try to extract with jq:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPatchBaseline" --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxx --max-errors "1" --parameters '{"Operation":["Install"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --output-s3-bucket-name "ssm" --region "us-east-1" | jq
```

Non selected output:

```
    {
  "Command": {
    "CommandId": "7312718d-2327-43g4-bffc-093a0901a13c",
    "DocumentName": "AWS-RunPatchBaseline",
    "Comment": "",
    "ExpiresAfter": 1535382731.286,
    "Parameters": {
      "Operation": [
        "Install"
      ]
    },
    "InstanceIds": [
      "i-xxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "Targets": [],
    "RequestedDateTime": 1535378531.286,
    "Status": "Pending",
     "StatusDetails": "Pending",
    "OutputS3BucketName": "ssm",
    "OutputS3KeyPrefix": "",
    "MaxConcurrency": "50",
    "MaxErrors": "1",
     "TargetCount": 1,
    "CompletedCount": 0,
    "ErrorCount": 0,
    "ServiceRole": "",
    "NotificationConfig": {
      "NotificationArn": "",
      "NotificationEvents": [],
      "NotificationType": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I would have thought I could use this command to get the CommandID string:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPatchBaseline" --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --max-errors "1" --parameters '{"Operation":["Install"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --output-s3-bucket-name "ssm" --region "us-east-1" | jq -r '.Command[].CommandID'
```

But that gives me this error:

```
 jq: error (at <stdin>:33): Cannot index string with string "CommandID"
```

Any ideas on how to extract that?

Comment: Downvoted the question. Please take the time to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you tell me which part you felt was not compliant to mvce?

Comment: Can you tell me what you've simplified here? The shell command? The json blob? Especially the json blob does a) contain tons of unnecessary  information while not b) being valid json, meaning not helpful for answering the question.

Comment: I did perhaps fail to add more simplification to the command by proving alternate variations, my assumption was that it could add confusion and that anyone with enough knowledge of jq could easily answer this.... which is what happened.

Comment: You can still edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in your JSON Command is not an array object.

If you require the value of CommandId change your jq to 'jq .Command.CommandId'

Comment: As yes haha! It was hiding from me!

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `"Command"` key is not a list; it's simply another object that has `CommandID` as a key. You just want

```
... | jq -r '.Command.CommandID'
```

The filter `.Command[]` returns the sequence of *values* of the object, so the error you are getting results from the attempt to evaluate something like `"7312718d-2327-43g4-bffc-093a0901a13c".Command`, not `{"Command: ...}.Command`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a back tick at the end? That or using a single quote does not appear to work - with a single quote I get: q: 1 compile error
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Nope, just a typo.